# LINQ - Different syntax style, different result?

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone tell me the difference the following two LINQ statements please?

```
var ChkUnique = DB.BusinessFile.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ROCNo == txtBoxID.Text);
```

and

```
var ChkUnique = from c in DB.BusinessFile 
                where c.ROCNo == (string)txtBoxID.Text 
                select c;
```

`ChkUnique != null` returns `false` for the top one when a match cannot be found and `true` for the latter and I can't figure out why this is happening.

I'm new to LINQ so I could have missed something really basic but its driving me nuts at the moment.

Comment: Note that you can make the second one equivalent to the first like this: `var ChkUnique = (from c in DB.BusinessFile where c.ROCNo == (string)txtBoxID.Text select c).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second code is returning an object that represents the query you are calling; it will never be null. Though once enumerated, it could be an empty collection. (still not null, though)

Your first is calling FirstOrDefault, which is forcing a single result into a single variable, returning null if there are no results. If you did `Where` instead of `FirstOrDefault`, you would have the same result both times.

Comment: Also if you end the latter with the same `(from c in DB.BusinessFile 
                where c.ROCNo == (string)txtBoxID.Text 
                select c).FirstOrDefault()`. Choose after readability!

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is using [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) and the second one is [LINQ Query Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx).

In your first methods `FirstOrDefault`, returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements. Here you are working on objects so your default return is `NULL` if your result does not contain any element.

On another hand your second statement always return `IEnumerable<T>` collection type value and it will never null. just you can check whether collection contain items using the Collection's `Count` property.

If you use Extension method `.Where()` in your first statement then it will equivalent to second one.

Check the specified links for detail information and differences.